# pandas failing with variable columns

Tags: python, file, pandas, multiple-columns

my file is this

```
    4 7 a a
    s g 6 8 0 d
    g 6 2 1 f 7 9 
    f g 3 
    1 2 4 6 8 9 0
```

I was using pandas to save it in form of pandas object. But I am getting the following error 
`pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 3, saw 8`

The code I used was
`file = pd.read_csv("a.txt",dtype = None,delimiter = " ")`

Can anyone suggest an idea to include the file as such ?

Comment: Do you know, how many columns there can be? Or that is uncertain too? Like here, if 7 is max columns, there is way.

Comment: I am not sure of the number of columns too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
In [50]: !type temp.csv
4,7,a,a
s,g,6,8,0,d
g,6,2,1,f,7,9
f,g,3
1,2,4,6,8,9,0
```

Read the csv to list of lists and then convert to DataFrame.

```
In [51]: pd.DataFrame([line.strip().split(',') for line in open('temp.csv', 'r')])
Out[51]:
   0  1  2     3     4     5     6
0  4  7  a     a  None  None  None
1  s  g  6     8     0     d  None
2  g  6  2     1     f     7     9
3  f  g  3  None  None  None  None
4  1  2  4     6     8     9     0
```

Comment: Thanks, This was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas this will raise an error because the function expects there to be a certain number of columns, in this case 6, but when it got to the third row it encountered 8. One way to handle this is to not read the the rows that have more columns than the first row of the dataframe. This could be done using `error_bad_lines` parameter. This is what the docs say about `error_bad_lines`:

> error_bad_lines : boolean, default True Lines with too many fields
>   (e.g. a csv line with too many commas) will by default cause an
>   exception to be raised, and no DataFrame will be returned. If False,
>   then these “bad lines” will dropped from the DataFrame that is
>   returned. (Only valid with C parser)

So you could do this:

```
>>> file = pd.read_csv("a.txt",dtype = None,delimiter = " ",error_bad_lines=False)
Skipping line 3: expected 6 fields, saw 8
Skipping line 5: expected 6 fields, saw 7

>>> file
     4    7    a  a.1
s g  6  8.0  0.0    d
f g  3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Or you could use `skiprows` parameter to skip the rows that you would like, this is what the docs have to say about `skiprows`:

> skiprows : list-like or integer, default None Line numbers to skip
>   (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file

Comment: I should add that if you add commas to the file as delimiter, you could add extra commas to rows with less data and it will work fine.

Comment: I dont want those lines to be omitted

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of @Zero's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40881292/19007114), but without the simplistic `str.strip().split()`, which can be error prone with some CSV content (e.g. strings that contain commas).

```py
csv_data = """\
4,7,a,a
s,g,6,8,0,d
g,6,2,1,f,7,9
f,g,3
1,2,4,6,8,9,0
"""

pd.DataFrame( [ pd.read_csv( StringIO(line), header=None ).squeeze().tolist() for line in StringIO(csv_data) ] )

   0  1  2     3     4     5    6
0  4  7  a     a  None  None  NaN
1  s  g  6     8     0     d  NaN
2  g  6  2     1     f     7  9.0
3  f  g  3  None  None  None  NaN
4  1  2  4     6     8     9  0.0
```

NOTE: for some reason the last column shows `NaN` instead of `None`.  I presume it's a bug in the Debian 10 Buster `python3-pandas` (0.23.3) package?

I use this technique in a slightly different way - to get values as a list of lists.

```py
[ pd.read_csv( StringIO(line), header=None ).squeeze().tolist() for line in StringIO(s1) ]

[[4, 7, 'a', 'a'], ['s', 'g', 6, 8, 0, 'd'], ['g', 6, 2, 1, 'f', 7, 9], ['f', 'g', 3], [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 0]]
```